# How to view, modify database of a existing firebase android project from firebase console/android studio from a different google account?

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-console

I have a firebase android project which I had created long back. I have lost the details of the google account which was integrated to and not able to retrieve it. Right now, I tried to connect the project to the firebase with a different google account by changing the **google-services.json** file and rebuilt the project in the android studio where the build is successful.

I was wondering if there is a way to view, modify and change the existing database structure using the firebase console/android studio. 
                                           OR
How to view, retrieve, modify database/DB structure of an existing firebase android project from firebase console/android studio from a different google account?

Is there a way to view the firebase database in android studio? Any references, guidelines will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There are no tools for working with Firebase project data in Android Studio.  You have to use the Firebase web console, or build your own tools.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way I can access the database of this existing android project using firebase web console as in view/modify??

Comment: Yes, as I said, use the console. It's the same thing you used to download google-services.json.

Comment: I am a little confused here, I have connected the project using firebase web console and synced in android studio using a different google account from the one the project has been created. I am still not able to view the existing database that is already there in the project, but I am being asked to create a new database.

Comment: If you are using the Firebase assistant in Android Studio, you should stop using, because it's buggy. Just follow the instructions in the documentation on the web.